# Cloaking Specific Text on Web Page

Tags: php, javascript, html, cloaking

Is there any way I could make specific text strings "invisible" on my web page?

For example,

If I were to specify the string "hxxp://nullrefer.com/?", I would need that text to appear invisible on my page everywhere it's mentioned, automatically.

So, if the url "hxxp://nullrefer.com/?hxxp://www.Amazon.com" were to be mentioned on my page, viewers would only be able to see the "hxxp://www.Amazon.com" portion of it.  Almost as if you were to turn the Opacity of to the text down to 0% for that specific string only, everywhere it appears on the page, automatically.  I need it to still physically be there, but be as invisible as possible.

Are there any scripts out there for something like this?

Comment: *Are there any scripts out there for something like this?* Why don't you write one?

Comment: I don't know where to begin...?

I'm not sure of how to specify the text string and what function should be used to cloak the text.

I'm new.

Comment: You don't just want opacity 0% because that would leave an empty space where the invisible letters are. Given that you are talking about URLs can't you use standard anchor elements: `<a href="hxxp://nullrefer.com/?hxxp://www.Amazon.com">hxxp://www.Amazon.com</a>`?

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all of the links on your page with whatever you specify instead of nullrefer..
Also if you only want it to affect a certain id/class you can do it with

`a[i].parentNode.id == "someid"` `a[i].parentNode.className == "someid"`

Pretty basic and awful but it'll do what you want.  Add it to the bottom of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    if(a[i].parentNode.id == "someid")
    a[i].href = "hxxp://www.nullrefer.com/?" + a[i].href;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm putting this script on my page, but it seems to do nothing... I've experimented changing the "someid" to "http://" and still have no luck.  Any ideas?